# rawPassword and encodedPassword both are coming as same string using BcryptPasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring-security, bcrypt

I'm new to spring security. I have used Spring boot, spring security and JWT to secure the authentication of a React application. I'm getting the following error:

"o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Encoded password does not look like BCrypt"

in the console when using BcryptPasswordEncoder. When I switched to NoOpPasswordEncoder it is working fine. I added breakpoints in the BCryptPasswordEncoder.class. I have added breakpoints at the entry of encode() and matches() methods. The BCRYPT_PATTERN used in the BcryptPasswordEncoder class is:

```
private Pattern BCRYPT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\A\\$2(a|y|b)?\\$(\\d\\d)\\$[./0-9A-Za-z]{53}");
```

During debugging I found that in the encode() method the rawPassword is userNotFoundPassword and in the matches method the rawPassword and the encodedPassword both are same string (same with the user entered password). Since the rawPassword and encodedPassword both are equal with the user entered password it is failing at the following condition check and throwing the warning message in the console and then failing the validation.

```
if (!this.BCRYPT_PATTERN.matcher(encodedPassword).matches()) {
            this.logger.warn("Encoded password does not look like BCrypt");
            return false;
        }
```

userNotFoundPassword is coming as rawPassword in encode() method
[image]

rawPassword and encodedPassword both are coming as same string in matches() method
[image]

I have no idea about why this is happening. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning is logged when the password that you are matching on isn't bcrypt hashed.

A bcrypt hashed string looks something like:

```
$2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG
```

You can see for instance that the first 3 characters ($2a) are in the regexp, as these characters denote what bcrypt version is being used.

It is most likely that the password you are fetching and trying to match on are not hashed with bcrypt, so check your database what the passwords look like at rest.

If they are in plain text then you need to hash the passwords and store them in the database before trying to do matches on them.

Comment: You are correct the passwords in the database was in plain text. I hashed the passwords using BCrypt algorithm. After that when I'm trying to login, I'm getting "Bad credentials exception".  During debugging, the rawPassword in encode method is still showing as userNotFoundPassword. And both the rawPassword and the encodedPassword arguments in the matches method are showing as a long string which is the hashed value of the entered password. Please help.

Comment: This has now turned into a new question. You either update your question with the new code including steps to reproduce, or you start a new question.

Comment: This was my mistake, I passed the hashed password as argument to the AuthenticationManager.authenticate() method instead of the user entered password which caused the issue. Now, I have corrected this, and it is working fine. thanks!

Comment: Next time you should check these things BEFORE asking on stack overflow. Stack overflow is not a forum, its your last resort.